# Required: no arguments, found: String

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

just wondering if you guys could help me with this error I've been trying to
fix for the past hour or so.

I'm calling the function with the error in this block of code:

```
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
static int xIn, yIn;
static String name = "";
static String input = "";

public static void main(String[] args){         
    if(args.length < 2){
        System.out.println("Not enough arguments. Temination.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(args.length > 2){
        System.out.println("Too many arguments. Termination.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    BottyBot.Test(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    BottyBot.Greet();
}
```

And the BottyBot.Greet() function is:

```
public static void Greet(){
    name = scan.nextLine("Hello, what is your name? ");
    do{
        input = scan.nextLine("Would you like to order some boots, " + name + "? (y/n) ");
        if(input == "y"){
            System.out.println("Great! Let's get started.");
            break;
        }
        else if(input == "n"){
            System.out.println("Come back next time, " + name + ".");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid response. Try again.");
        }
    }
    while(true);
}
```

I'm getting two errors at both Scanner lines. Specifically, it is saying

```
error: method nextLine in class Scanner cannot be applied to given types;
    next = scan.nextLine("Hello, what is your name? ");
               ^
required: no arguments
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

It'd be great if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong! Thanks!

Comment: `Scanner.nextLine()` doesn't take arguments. You're providing an argument. What you're doing is wrong, and the compiler is telling you that.

Comment: As the error clearly say.. there is no argument with `nextLine()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write like this, as [`scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method does not take any argument

```
System.out.println("Hello, what is your name? ");
name = scan.nextLine();
```

Printing part is done by `System.out.println()` and scanning part is done by `scanner.nextLine()`.

---

```
error: method nextLine in class Scanner cannot be applied to given types;
next = scan.nextLine("Hello, what is your name? ");
           ^
required: no arguments
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

This message gives you a clear hint.
It states that `actual and formal argument lists differ in length`. So here the argument denotes method argument and required is mentioned as `no arguments`, instead found is `String` i.e. "Hello, what is your name? ".

Comment: Hey thanks for that, didn't realize it was such a small error. Been working for hours trying to fix it too!

Comment: your welcome. From error you will get the hint. If it answers your question, then you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing what the `Scanner` does. This reminds me of the `input` function in QBasic, although I might be incorrect.

As the error states, the `nextLine()` method does not take any arguments, but you are passing a string to it. From what I am understanding, your intention is to print to console and read from it. To do this, you will need to split your scanner statements into two. Given this:

```
name = scan.nextLine("Hello, what is your name? ");
```

Turn it into:

```
System.out.println("Hello, what is your name?");    //Print to console.
name = scan.nextLine();                             //Read from it.
```

The same goes for the other.

Answer (score 0):

[`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) does not take any arguments, it just reads a line.

You could use this:

```
System.out.println("Hello, what is your name?");
name = scan.nextLine();
```

And

```
System.out.println("Would you like to order some boots, " + name + "? (y/n) ");
input = scan.nextLine();
```